# Peg Game: best place to place ball such that it lands in the target cell

Tags: algorithm, math, statistics

Source: [Facebook Hacker Cup](http://www.facebook.com/hackercup) [Qualification Round 2011](http://www.facebook.com/hackercup/problems.php?round=4)

At the arcade, you can play a simple game where a ball is dropped into the top of the game, from a position of your choosing. There are a number of pegs that the ball will bounce off of as it drops through the game. Whenever the ball hits a peg, it will bounce to the left with probability 0.5 and to the right with probability 0.5. The one exception to this is when it hits a peg on the far left or right side, in which case it always bounces towards the middle.

When the game was first made, the pegs where arranged in a regular grid. However, it's an old game, and now some of the pegs are missing. Your goal in the game is to get the ball to fall out of the bottom of the game in a specific location. Given the arrangement of the game, how can we determine the optimal place to drop the ball, such that the probability of getting it to this specific location is maximized?

The image below shows an example of a game with five rows of five columns. Notice that the top row has five pegs, the next row has four pegs, the next five, and so on. With five columns, there are four choices to drop the ball into (indexed from 0). Note that in this example, there are three pegs missing. The top row is row 0, and the leftmost peg is column 0, so the coordinates of the missing pegs are (1,1), (2,1) and (3,2). In this example, the best place to drop the ball is on the far left, in column 0, which gives a 50% chance that it will end in the goal.

```
x.x.x.x.x
 x...x.x
x...x.x.x
 x.x...x
x.x.x.x.x
 G
```

`x` indicates a peg, `.` indicates empty space.

Comment: Just noting, this round has now ended.

Comment: Does the ball always drop straight down in this simulated game? Meaning, if it bounces to the left in a real game, it would follow an arc. I assume this won't happen here?

Comment: @Lass Bouncing left here means going from `cell[r][c]` to `cell[r+1][c-1]`. Hope that's clear.

Comment: TAKE NOTE: This is a modification of a binomial tree, as used in financial maths: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_options_pricing_model

Comment: @Phil H: the boundary conditions (Neumann) makes it a binomial tree for lookback options :)

Comment: Actually @Phil H.'s remark yields a solution strategy using an analogue of the Feynman-Kac theorem. I post a worked solution as soon as I get home.

Comment: @Phil H: from what I've seen of facebook puzzles, they usually take real problems and change the context and wording :) Well done spotting the origin!

Answer (score 4):

Start at the bottom and assign a probability of 1 to the goal and 0 to other slots. Then for the next row up, assign probabilities as follows:

```
1) if there is no peg, use the probability directly below.
2) for a peg, use the average of the probabilities in the adjacent columns one row down.
```

This will simply propagate the probabilities to the top where each slot will be assigned the probability of reaching the goal *from that slot*. No tree, no recursion.

Answer (score 2):

We can solve this problem using probability theory. We drop the ball in a position and recursively split the ball's path in its one (at the sidewall) or two possible directions. At the first step, we know with probability 1 the position of the ball (we are dropping it after all!). At each subsequent split into two directions, the probability halves. If we end up at the bottom row in the target location, we add the probability of path taken to our total. Repeat this process for all starting positions and take the highest probability of reaching the target.

We can improve this algorithm by removing the recursion and processing row-by-row using dynamic programming. Start with the first row set to all 0, except for the starting location which we set to 1. Then calculate the probabilities of reaching each cell in the next row by starting with an array of 0's and. For each cell in our current row, add half its probability to the cell to its left in the next row and half to its right, unless its against the sidewall in which case we add the full probability to the single cell. Continue doing this for each row until reaching the final row.

So far we've neglected the missing pegs. We can take them into account by having three probabilities for each cell: one for each direction the ball is currently travelling. In the end, we sum up all thre as direction doesn't matter.

Comment: I like the dynamic programming solution... but I was thinking that there could be a way of exploiting the fact that we know where the goal is, by iterating backwards. This would avoid computing values that we are not interested in (like the probability of falling in the hole on the right of the goal).

Comment: @Matthieu It should work, and it will save you a factor of C in the runtime.

Answer (score 0):

This question was in Facebook Hacker Cup 2011.

marcog solution seems correct, but I solved a bit different. I solved like this:

1. Setup board: Read input, setup a NxM board, read missing pegs and insert holes on the board.
2. For each possible initial drop hole, do a BFS as follow:

   - Drop hole has 1.0 initial probability.
   - From current state you can either go down, left, right, left and right.
   - If you can only go down, left, or right, sum the current state probability and add it to the queue if it is not already on the queue. For example: if you are at (1, 2) with probability 0.5 and can only go down, sum 0.5 to state (2,2) and add it to the queue if it is not on the queue already.
   - If you can go left and right, sum half the current state probability to each possible next state and add them to the queue if they are not already there. For example: if you are at (3, 3) with probability 0.5 and can go both left and right, add 0.25 to (4, 2) and 0.25 to (4, 4) and them to the queue if they are not already there.
3. Update current best
4. Print global best.

My solution (not the cleanest code) in cpp can be downloaded from: https://github.com/piva/Programming-Challenges/blob/master/peggame.cpp

Hope that helped...

Answer (score 0):

Observations:

1. For a given starting position, on each row there is a distribution of probabilities
2. From one **full** row to the next, the distribution will simply be blurred except for the edges.
3. Where there are holes, we will see predictable deviation from the blurring in (2)
4. We could separate these deviations out, since the balls are dropped one at a time, so the probabilities obey the superposition principle (quantum computers would be ideal here).
5. Separating out the deviations, we can see that really there is a set of holes overlaid on a grid of pegs, so we can calculate the distribution from the complete set of pegs first (easy) and then go through the pegs individually to see their effect - this assumes that there are more pegs than holes!
6. An edge is really a mirror - we can calculate for an infinite array of these mirrored virtual boards rather than using if conditions for the boundaries.

So I would start at the bottom, in the desired position, and spread the probability. The missing pegs effectively just skip a row, so you keep a register of vertically falling balls.

Ideally, I would start with a complete (fibonacci) tree, and for each missing of the missing pegs on a row add in the effect of them being missing.

Answer (score 0):

`O(R*C)` solution

`dp[i][j]` gives the probability of the ball reaching the goal slot if it is currently at row i and in slot j.

The base case has `dp[R-1][goal] = 1.0` and all other slots in row R-1 to 0.0

The recurrence then is

```
dp[i][j] = dp[i + 2][j] if the peg below is missing 
dp[i][j] = dp[i + 1][left] if the peg is on the right wall 
dp[i][j] = dp[i + 1][right] if the peg is on the left wall 
dp[i][j] = (dp[i + 1][left] + dp[i + 1][right]) / 2 otherwise
```